# Suggested order to view WWDC 2010 videos

Tags: iphone, ios, wwdc

I got WWDC 2010 videos. However, there are 68 of them and thats for iPhone only with each video having an average of 50 mins.

I know you can watch them independently depending on your interest. However, is there a suggested order in which to view them if you wanna watch all of them? Say as a new developer, I wanna view them and get a general idea about all the frameworks discussed. Should I view, for e.g., in order of session number in the file name of the videos(Starts at 101 and ends at 425. Session 101 - What's New in Cocoa Touch). Does that indicate the levels (like in university where 101 is the most basic course and 400s are the advanced courses)?

Just wanted thoughts from the community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is as you say - independently depending on your interest. Obviously there are some general ones that will benefit new developers and you should not discount the less technical sessions like 100 "Usable By Everybody".

100 - Here's where you pick some starters and then target the areas you think you need or that you are led to after watching other videos. To get started I'd pick 100 and 103 (especially if you have not been a long-term iPhone user). 104 (scroll views), 110 (text handling), 115 (Core Location), 118 (Core Data), 119 (Shared contacts), 124 (Foundation), 128 (Table views) I think are your "bread and butter" sessions. But none of these should be left out in the long term particularly 113 (effective Objective C), 125 (internationalization), 131 (performance optimization) and 137 (core data performance). And get Marcus Zarra's "Core Data" book too.

200 - Networks, GCD, Security etc. - useful stuff but you can leave it for a bit. Maybe get to session 206 quickly though, you will need blocks for animation.

300 is tools. You need at least a few of these to understand Xcode and how to use it efficiently to develop and debug. Whether you start with Xcode 4 or 3 is your choice, but there is no guarantee about when 4 is available and you must develop apps for the store today with 3. Don't neglect instruments! You absolutely need to know how to check your app to get memory usage and core animation, amongst other things, right. You'll find instruments used a lot in the other sessions particularly the ones talking about efficient drawing.

400 is visual and audible stuff. If you're going to be doing business apps you might leave this section until last but you would be surprised how useful it is, or how often apps you would not suspect use some of the techniques presented.

500 series is the web stuff. Are you going to deliver content through streaming over the web, CSS, will you be developing Safari extensions? For me as an iPhone developer this bunch is way down the priority list.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for :) ... Can I get you a beer :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are a new iPhone developer I think I would perhaps watch the 100 level videos, but also go look for the Stanford iPhone development videos on iTunes which are really more in depth as far as learning development.  WWDC is more of an overview or talking in depth about specific frameworks;  You need the kind of deeper overview the Stanford course provides.  Program as you go along to really learn the material.

http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewPodcast?id=395631522

Comment: +1 for Stanfords iPhone programming CS193P course

Comment: Stanford CS193P are great videos. I followed them for two courses ... the new ones (ongoing - Fall 2010) look great too. I am not new to iPhone prog but rather new to iOS 4.x ... so thats the reason I wanted to checkout WWDC videos ... I had been to WWDC 2009 but at that time I was a real beginner and was lost. But thanks for the comment. Hopefully future visitors can find this great resource if they are not aware :)